# Generate PDF via objective-C in Cordova app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I followed this guide
http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/
to generate PDF from a UIWebView.
What I actually need to do is generate a PDF from the cordova UIWebView in my app.
Does someone know how to do this? I think it will be necessary to write a plugin for this..
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [KAPDFPlugin](https://github.com/kaar3k/KAPDFPLugin) .Add into the plugin into your project and follow the instructions to link it to your code.

Comment: Thank you for your work! I've tried to run your application but it crashes...after the second dialog ("o") the console says "Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now"
Any idea?

Comment: Please download the updated project let me know if any issues.

Comment: Well, the plugin works but in my project (Cordova 2.0.0), although I put plugin name and value in the cordova.plist file, the console says

ERROR: Plugin 'PDFGenerator' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
FAILED pluginJSON ={"className":"PDFGenerator","methodName":"generatePDF","arguments":["PDFGenerator2",1]}

Comment: I updated the project to 2.7.0 version and it works! Thanks so much for your work :)

Comment: Your welcome :) if your query is resolved you can accept the answer by checking the green tick mark.

Comment: Do you know about something similar for Android (Java) too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need a plugin for that.

You already have the native code you need, so it won't be difficult

Comment: I'm not very expert of this languages so, if you can, help me please

Comment: Start reading the plugin development guide http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide and let me know if you have any doubt, right now I don't have time to develop the plugin myself